# Setting the context-root in Spring Restdocs

Tags: java, spring, spring-restdocs

How do you set the context-root in the Spring Restdoc documentation?  I looked in the `uris()` for a way to set this, but it's not there.

If I add it directly to my `post()`, my test returns a 404.

Comment: This is probably key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435631/spring-rest-mock-context-path